# Is SUPEE-4814 genuine?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1, patches, promotions

I have come across an issue with shopping cart promotions on our site. It seems as though **there is a patch, SUPEE-4814, to resolve this**, but I can't find it on the https://magento.com/security/patches.

I have found links to this patch on GitHub (https://gist.github.com/piotrekkaminski/54529dadb0bc01a62a2d), but I don't know anything about the author. Is it a genuine patch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is a genuine patch. I'm not 100% sure why it's not included on the patches list though.

The **author is the Magento Lead Product Manager**, so you can totally trust him ;)

Comment: Thanks Raphael. Do you mean the issue only affects Enterprise or the patch only works with Enterprise? For info I manually made the diff changes on my 1.9.2 CE dev site and it resolved the issue so it seems as though it's OK with CE.

Comment: @jscar see my edit. It actually works for both EE and CE ;)

Answer (score 0):

This patch is for Magento EE, for EE_1.14.1.0 version. You can apply this patch if your Magento version is the same as this patch or lower version. If you have version greater than 1.14.1.0 then this change should be included. There is only one change, ine the way of validatin $item

```
-            if (parent::validate($item)) {
+            if (Mage_Rule_Model_Condition_Combine::validate($item)) {
```